# Check if K2 image exists in third party exention

Tags: templates, overrides, k2

I need to check if a K2 article image exist in a third party extension. If the image exist, it should be displayed otherwise, a default image should be fetched.

I am making the image path with :

```
$imagePath = "/media/k2/items/cache/".md5("Image" . $item->object_id )."_XS.jpg";
```

(`$item->object_id` is the article id) when the image exists, it is displayed.

I have tried several methods to check if the image exists with :

```
if (file_exists('http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $imagePath)) {}

if (@getimagesize('http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $imagePath)) {}
```

and with

```
if (JFile::exists('http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $imagePath)){}
```

The two first ones don't work and return false even when image exists and the last one breaks the whole page.

How can I check if the K2 article image exist?

Answer (score 1):

Most PHP file/image checking methods work on a local image.

If an image is stored in your site by a third-party extension, then you can also check it with a local path.

If an image is an external source and you have an Url, you have to download it to a temporary file, validate, return the status and delete the temporary file.

For example:

```
$imagefile = JInstallerHelper::downloadPackage($image_url);
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($imagefile);
```